# Discord py bot doesn't wait for user answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

So, i'm trying to do a command where user need to answer to a bot question, and depend on user answer the bot will do specific things, but the problem is that my bot is not waiting for answer, is sending the question, and if someone answer it will not do anything, here is basically the code :

```
async def suggestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You want to submit a suggestion?")
    message = await client.wait_for('messsage' ,timeout=20, check = lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)

    if message.content == "yes"  :
        await ctx.send("Good choice, now let's hear your suggestion : ")
    elif message.content == "no" :
        await ctx.send("Too bad, please use this command just if you have any ideas.")
```

Comment: You need to wait for `message` not `messsage` in `client.wait_for`.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled "message" with "messsage" (triple s)

Comment: bruh moment, i usually check the code after i write it but that "messsage" damn, seems like now it works, thanks, i guess

Answer (score 1):

you will have to do it this way, if you also want to use the timeout,  also replace the `messsage` with `message` :)

```
async def suggestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You want to submit a suggestion?")

    def check(message, user):
            _message = message
            return user == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
        message = await client.wait_for('message' ,timeout=20, check = check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        ctx.send("whoops, time's up!")
    else:
        if _message == "yes"  :
            await ctx.send("Good choice, now let's hear your suggestion : ")
        elif _message == "no" :
            await ctx.send("Too bad, please use this command just if you have any ideas.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your query:

```
import asyncio

async def suggestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You want to submit a suggestion?")

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
        message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=20,
                                        check=check)
        if message.content.lower() == "yes":
            await ctx.send("Good choice, now let's hear your suggestion : ")
        elif message.content.lower() == "no":
            await ctx.send("Too bad, please use this command just if you have any ideas.")

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("Oh no, you ran out of time!")
```

If you are going to have a timeout for `client.wait_for`, you will need to import the python package `asyncio` (`pip install asyncio` in the terminal should do it). Then, we check if the user said yes or no, and if it's been 20 seconds and still no response, then it is a timeout error.